# Error when trying to include a class inside a php file that was called from ajax, in vtiger crm

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, vtiger

i have this code which call a php file to get the data with ajax

```
function checkInfo($campaignId){
    //var idc = JSON.stringify($campaignId);
    var data = {
        "action": $campaignId
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/modules/SomeFolder/testAjax.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function(results){
            alert(results);
        },
        error:function (data){
            console.log(data);
        }

    });
}
```

**testAjax.php**

```
require_once ('Mandrill.php'); //displays an error.
```

The mandrill file has the class Mandrill but also have require_once('somefile') which causing the error class not found

**EDIT 1**
The mandrill class works fine i get the error only when i do a ajax call of hte file.

```
**Mandrill.php**
require_once('libraries/src-api/soemthing/Mandrill.php')
 class EmailCampaign_mandrill {
 //code here
 }
```

**Error that i get in console log**
require_once(libraries/soemthing/Mandrill.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: Mandrill.php file seems have no any class. pls add full file code

Comment: Please include the complete error in your question.

Comment: It's probably because of the require_once acting different depending on which URL you are calling (See include_path).

Comment: im calling the funciton "checkInfo" from a layout and the modules are somewhere else, the code works perfect when i do not add the classes to the "testAjax.php" i can run php code but im not able to interact with other classes

Answer (score 0):

The path you could see in the error message `require_once(libraries/..soemthing/Mandrill.php)` is badly formatted: it lacks a slash between `..` and `soemthing`.
It should be like `require_once("libraries/../soemthing/Mandrill.php")`

Comment: i did that on propose i did not add the full path here

Comment: Did you checked that the file is in the correct directory and have enough rights (read or execute rights) ?

Comment: yes everything is fine the app work fine, the problem shows only when i do a Ajax call

Comment: `libraries/src-api/soemthing/Mandrill.php`is a relative path. Relative to the path of the one used in `require_once ('Mandrill.php');`. Relative itself to the one used in you ajax request: `/modules/SomeFolder/testAjax.php`. So It looks for a file located in `/modules/SomeFolder/libraries/src-api/soemthing/Mandrill.php`. Check  if this path valid.

Comment: no that is not a valid path it has to go to another directory and not /modules/SomeFolder/libraries/src-api/soemthing/Mandrill.php

Comment: This is the cause of the error you have.

Comment: Any idea how can i resolve?

Comment: This is what i said: the path i gave to you is the path resolved by PHP which is not correct. So correct it.